# Difference between totalSize() and dataSize() in mognodb

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Guys i am running this command in terminal because i want to find out the collection size(data+indexes).The problem is that the command `db.mongodbbucketright2index.dataSize()` returns `368274259 bytes` and `db.mongodbbucketright2index.totalSize()` returns `74448896 bytes`.Why is this happening .I know that `totalSize` gives  me the `data size + indexes size` but whats up with `datasize` and why it returns so many bytes?

Comment: @prasad_ Yes i did.But i dont understand the difference between them. "size" : 368274259,"totalSize" : 74448896 can you explain?

Comment: Use `db.collection.stats()` method result's fields `size` (size of all records) and `totalIndexSize` (size of all indexes) for a collection.

Comment: @prasad_ so when i execute the command ```db.collection,stats()``` the field ```size``` gives me the size of the collection and ```totalIndexSize``` gives me the index size only?

Comment: See this [output](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/collStats/#std-label-collStats-output) details from the command for the field info.

Comment: @prasad_ Yes now i understand.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With WiredTiger data is compressed in disk by default. `dataSize()` returns the size of the data without compression. `storageSize()` returns the size in disk, which, since it's compressed, it should be a smaller number.

Both `dataSize()` and `storageSize()` exclude index data. To check the size of the indices you can use `totalIndexSize()` and `totalSize()`.